# Why were there pennies nailed to an old oak?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

After Jaime resolves the siege of Raventree, in *A Dance with Dragons*, he and his hostage Hoster come across an old tree nailed with pennies.

> He tried to count **the pennies nailed to the old oak**, but there were too many of them and he kept losing count. What's that all about? The Blackwood boy would tell him if he asked, but that would **spoil the mystery**.

I waited until the end of the book, and I still don't get the joke... maybe it will be revealed in the next book?

Comment: [Looks like we dunno.](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pennytree)

Comment: It's speculated that this is meta-commentary: ["The series as a whole invites to speculation, and that is half the fun - but one shouldn’t expect all the mysteries to be explicitly revealed in the two books to come."](http://asoiafuniversity.tumblr.com/post/145454644275/but-that-would-spoil-the-mystery-the-pennytree)

Comment: Nailing a penny to an oak tree is an old custom to ward off evil spirits.  If you can't count them, the spirits are messing with your mind.

Comment: Obviously, long ago, an impetuous Lannister boy was passing by on a horse, got hit by a low tree branch, and almost died.  Since then, he was more cautious.  TL,DR: the tree knocked a lot of sense into him, well, the Lannisters always pay their debts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably some form of **[wish tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wish_Tree)**.

> *[excerpt from wikipedia]* A wish tree is an individual tree, usually distinguished by species, position or appearance, which is used as an object of wishes and offerings. Such trees are identified as possessing a special religious or spiritual value. By tradition, believers make votive offerings in order to gain from that nature spirit, saint or goddess fulfillment of a wish.

We can assume that Jaime is not familiar with the tradition and/or it is not a common one. It seems that the tree predates the settlement that has built near it

> [Pennytree](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pennytree) is situated near the Widow's Wash between two grassy hills known as the Teats. It is named for a huge old oak tree that grows by the duck pond, to which hundreds of copper pennies have been nailed.